# ASP.NET How to validate if a box within a checkboxlist is selected (1 and only 1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to get a little help with a validation function for an assignment of mine.  I'm completely stuck on it.  We had to create a web form with several fields.  I've set everything else up (user name longer than 6 characters; password hidden with asterisks, longer than 8 characters, and contains 1 upper & 1 lower case letter, 1 number, and 1 special character, etc.).

The instructions is that every field needs to have a something entered.  We were supposed to create various fields, but one of the instructions was to create a checkboxlist with 5 boxes.  The instructions did not specify that only once answer was to be selected, however, that is what I'm going for.

The checkboxlist is for age demographics....for the user to select what age range they fall into.  This is what I have:

ASPX File:

```
<tr class="Specific">
    <td>
       <asp:Label
          ID="AgeLabel"
          style="vertical-align:middle"
          runat="server"
          Text="Age Demographic:"
          Font-Bold="True"
          ForeColor="#016882">
       </asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
       <asp:CheckBoxList ID="Age" runat="server" Width="385px">
       </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

ASPX.CS File:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      Age.Items.Add("&nbsp;18-24");
      Age.Items.Add("&nbsp;25-34");
      Age.Items.Add("&nbsp;35-44");
      Age.Items.Add("&nbsp;45-54");
      Age.Items.Add("&nbsp;55+");
      MyFormPanel.Visible = true; // show the form
   } // End If
} // End Page_Load
```

This just populates the checkboxes for me.  I can't get any validator to work with this one.  So what I've done is create a function to run upon clicking a Submit button.  This function checks if there is only 1 box clicked.

```
protected void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int test = 0;
   result.Text = "";

   foreach (ListItem lstItem in Age.Items)
   {
      if (lstItem.Selected == true)
      {
         test += 1;
      }
   }
   if (test == 0)
   {
      result.Text = "Please select one of the boxes in Age Demographic.";
   }
   else if (test != 1)
   {
      result.Text = "Please select only 1 checkbox in Age Demographic.";
   }
   else
   {
      return;
   }
}
```

My question is...how can I tie this function back into page validation?  My thought process is that there is something called Page.IsValid that is a boolean, correct?  My thought was that I can put something in this function that assigns IsValid to false and if this validation goes through, then it assigns IsValid to true.  Am I on the right path in thinking here?

I tried this in my code but it is telling me something about this property is read only.  I've got a lot of different RequiredFieldValidators and RegularExpressionValidators already set up to make sure textboxes aren't empty and that email addresses and phone numbers are formatted correctly, so I'm not sure how this function can play in with those.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Now I'm being told that the user can select more than one checkbox, so checkboxlist is more appropriate.  But how would we validate the data and include the information within the validation summary?

Comment: It will be simpler to use RadoButtonList instead of Checkbox list, if you have to select only one item from multiple choices.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check if at least one item selected in checklistbox?

If so, maybe you can try to script to achieve it. Here is a simple demo.

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateCheckBoxList(sender, args) {
    var checkBoxList = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>");
    var checkboxes = checkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var isValid = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            isValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    args.IsValid = isValid;
}
</script>
```

**CustomValidator**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ErrorMessage="You need to select at least one item." ForeColor="Red" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBoxList" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnCheck" runat="server" OnClick="BtnCheck_Click" Text="Check" />
</form>
```

If catch the exception `System.InvalidOperationException`, add the following statement in `Web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```